# Radio Button Reset using vue js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuejs3

In this below code click on the reset button to uncheck all radio buttons but I have to click on the reset button to check the default radio button

```
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(val, key) in list">
    <input type="radio" name="radio" :value="val" v-model="selected" :id="val" @click="uncheck( val )"><label :for="val">{{ val }}</label>
  </div>
  <button @click="uncheckAll">Reset</button>
</div>
```

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        list: ['one', 'two', 'three'],
        selected: 'two',
        previous: null,
    },
    methods: {
        uncheck: function(val) {
            if (val == this.previous) {
                this.selected = false;
            }
            this.previous = this.selected;
        },
        uncheckAll: function() {
            this.selected = false;
        },
    }
})
```

It's working fine but I need to reset the selected value, for that, I can not find any solution there.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at following snippet (just set default value on reset):

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      list: [ 'one', 'two', 'three' ],
      selected: 'two',
    }
  },
  methods : {
    uncheck(){
      this.selected = 'two';
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(val, key) in list">
    <input type="radio" name="radio" :value="val" v-model="selected" :id="val">
    <label :for="val">{{ val }}</label>
  </div>
  <button @click="uncheck">Reset</button>
  {{ selected }}
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping but not solve issue. My code given same result to your code .but i have click on reset to checked default value two.

Comment: @Mitali Patel hey mate, then I didn't understood your question. So you want to check default value (two) when reseted?

Comment: Yes, i want to check default value Two when i click on reset button

Comment: Check again please, I updated my answer